# Prove that up to isomorphism there are exactly two graphs s.t. there at most two vertices with same degree.

Tags: graph-theory, induction

I've proven the following:
For each $n\in\mathbb{N},n\geq 2$ there exists a graph on $n$ vertices such that all degrees are distinct except two. Formally for each $n$ there exists a graph on vertices $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ such that there exists at most one pair $i\neq j$, such that $\deg v_i = \deg v_j$. The construction goes by induction. Either the graph is contains a degree $0$ vertex, so the highest degree is $n-2$ and adding a vertex and joining it to everyone else gets the thing done. If it does not contain a degree $0$ vertex, then adding a new vertex and joining it to noone gets the thing done.

I am curious whether this construction leads to an unique graph. More precisely, I would like to show the following:

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there are, up to isomorphism, exactly two graphs on $n$ vertices $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ whose degree sequence satisfies that for at most one pair $i\neq j$ $\deg v_i = \deg v_j$. One of them is disconnected and one of them is connected.

I tried approaching this by induction. The base step for $n=2$ is trivial. There are exactly two graphs on $2$ vertices. Either there is the edge or there isn't.
Denote $G_{n,c}$ and $G_{n,d}$ the two graphs for degree $n$. (c - connected, d - disconnected). Assume a graph on $n+1$ vertices satisfying the conditions. Then either it has a vertex of degree $0$, then by removing it I get a graph on $n$ vertices and using the induction hypothesis, I can say it is isomorphic to $G_{n,c}$, because there was a vertex of degree $n-1$. Simillarly i can argue if there was no vertex of degree $0$, then there was a vertex with degree $n$ so by removing it, I get a graph on $n$ vertices that is isomorphic to $G_{n,d}$, because theres a degree $0$ vertex left. How to argue that this implies "uniqueness" for the $n+1$ vertices?

As a corollary, this would imply that $G_{n,c}$ is complement of $G_{n,d}$ for each $n$.

Comment: It seems like you've proved it.  If you have two graphs of order $n+1$ satisfying the condition, and each has a vertex of degree $n$, for example, then the subgraphs formed by deleting these vertices are isomorphic, and the isomorphism is easily extended to the original graphs.